# How to extract several 'Numeric value' from Cell of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a DataFrame like the one below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = {"a": ['123@abc#010', 'N_23xdbqwierj#23' , 'adfhN_21ejrn#17eh']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw)
```

And the result that I want to make are 3 different type of columns,

First is to extract the numeric value located in front of "@" ( Regardless of length )

Second is to extract the numeric value located behind of "#" ( Regardless of length )

Third is to extract the numeric value and Character located both sides of "_" ( Numeric value is regardless of length , but Character is only one letter )

Below is the result that I want to make. How can I achieve this?

```
extract_result = pd.DataFrame({"a": ['123@abc#010', 'N_23xdbqwierj#23' , 'adfhN_21ejrn#17eh'],
                               "Front@": ['123', '', ''],
                               "#Befind": ['010', '23', '17'],
                               "Both side_": ['', 'N23', 'N21']})
```

Comment: Hey, some questions; The things you want to extract from the signs, will they always be for example in the same structure? Or will there be for example 123a@ and then you only get 123 part?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Front@'] = df.a.str.extract(r'(\d+)(?=@)') 
df['#Befind'] = df.a.str.extract(r'(?<=#)(\d+)')
df['Both side_'] = df.a.str.extract('([a-zA-Z])(?=\_)')+df.a.str.extract('(?<=_)(\d+)')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

df
#                   a Front@ #Befind Both side_
#0        123@abc#010    123     010           
#1   N_23xdbqwierj#23             23        N23
#2  adfhN_21ejrn#17eh             17        N21
```